# Hibernate disconnect proxy when fetch=FetchType.LAZY

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, lazy-loading, eager-loading

```
@Entity
public class Master implements Serializable{
private List slaves;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "Master",fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
public List getSlaves() {
   return slaves;
}
}

I want this code to pass.

List m = createQuery("from Master where id=1").getResultList();
for (Master master : m) {
    assertNull(master.getSlaves());
}
```

I want getSlaves() to return null and not to initialize a proxy to connect to the database(this master has slaves and I dont want to delete them from database).

Is there any way to do that in Hibernate or JPA?

Is there also way of doing that when fetch is EAGER?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want a master that actually HAS slaves to return a null value for the list of slaves anyhow? Is this in a test context? Are you sure that this is what you want, and that you are on the right track?

Another ugly approach is to just set the list of slaves to null explicitly. This will ensure that getSlaves() returns null as long as you are in the same session, but nothing will actually be changed in the database (at least for hibernate). This approach works also for an eager collection.

Answer (score 1):

Silently failing proxies would be a tricky thing to debug.

After seeing the code of hibernate, I don't think you have an option to configure that. You can try to reflectively call `collection.setInitialized()`, to pseudo-initialize the collection, but that'd be ugly.

Answer (score 0):

A get on a Collection should not return null. You're setting a booby trap in your code by having it return null.

Rather have it return an empty set and assert that the set is empty

```
assertTrue(master.getSlaves().size() == 0);
```